# How to burn values from a shapefile into raster with gdal.Rasterize?

Tags: gdal, rasterization

I have this code to rasterise a point shapefile into raster TIFF.

```
vector_ds  = ogr.Open('stations.shp')
shp_layer = vector_ds.GetLayer()
shape_file = 'stations.shp'
output_raster = os.getcwd()+'/rasterized_points.tif'
pixel_size = 0.01
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = shp_layer.GetExtent()
ds = gdal.Rasterize(output_raster, shape_file, xRes=pixel_size, yRes=pixel_size, 
                    burnValues='data',outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], 
                    outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
ds = None
```

It works, but the result doesn't have values from 'data' column. Parameter 'attribute' of RasterizeOptions doesn't help neither. Can somebody explain, how I should make the Rasterize burn the right values (0,1,2,..) from shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that burnValues cannot be used like that.

See the api reference https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#RasterizeOptions.

> burnValues -- list of fixed values to burn into each band for all
> objects. Excusive with attribute.
> attribute --- identifies an
> attribute field on the features to be used for a burn-in value. The
> value will be burned into all output bands. Excusive with burnValues.

Change "burnValues" into "attribute" and it should work.

I made a test by digitizing two polygons with an attribute "data" of type integer. I places values 1 and 200 as "data". I modified your code just slightly.

```
from osgeo import gdal,ogr,osr
vector_ds  = ogr.Open('burn.jml')
jml_layer = vector_ds.GetLayer()
jml_file = 'burn.jml'
output_raster = rasterized_points.tif
pixel_size = 0.01
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = jml_layer.GetExtent()
ds = gdal.Rasterize(output_raster, jml_file, xRes=pixel_size, yRes=pixel_size, 
                    attribute='data',outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], 
                    outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
ds = None
```

Shortened gdalinfo about the output raster:

```
gdalinfo rasterized_points.tif -stats
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: rasterized_points.tif
Size is 6668, 4339
Origin = (300.000000000000000,683.391841779975266)
Pixel Size = (0.010000000000000,-0.010000000000000)
...
Band 1 Block=6668x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=200.000, Mean=54.468, StdDev=88.690
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=200
    STATISTICS_MEAN=54.468393933566
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=88.689808459494
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Maximum value in the raster is 200, just as the maximum value in the "data" column of the vector source.

Comment: No, attribute='data' doesn't help at all (I have written it in my question). I have a raster with correct georeference, but with 5 classes with 0 value, although it should be 0,1,2 and Nan.

Comment: Python code with "attribute" certainly works for me as you can see from the test that I added. Have you tried with data that does not have Nan values? What do you mean by "5 classes with 0 value"? If they are zeroes so don't they all fall into the same class?

Comment: My shapefile is a point shape. Is your file a point file?

Comment: Sorry, my statistics are also correct:

  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=2.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.006
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2
    STATISTICS_MEAN=2.4489795918367e-05
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.0063887187119569
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100

but it QGis it is shown with 0 values. It's strange that I cant see these pixels with 1 and 2 values.

Comment: Gdal_rasterize colors just one pixel for each point. And on the scale 0-255 pixels with values 1 and 2 are pretty close to black. Both together means that it is not a wonder that you do not see those pixels. I do not know your use case but it may be that gdal_rasterize is not the right tool for you.

Comment: and what one would be right?
I just need a raster from point shape file where each point is a pixel with value='data'

Comment: Depends on what you want as a result. If you want to visualize the data you'd have nice options for rendering if you open the data with QGIS, adjust the styles and export the map as raster. But don't you already have a file where each point is a pixel with value='data'? Gdalinfo -stats suggests so.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Sorry. Everything's fine )